# How to properly expose the results of my $http request in my service from my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Right now I am passing back the full results of the $http request back to the controller.  I do this so that I can show a local loading spinner, deal with any application errors returned from my API (eg - server-side validation), get any feedback messages in the data (eg - new user created successfully), deal with ajax error messages (some may be recoverable, others not depending on what you are doing).

Controller method:

```
MemberService.getMember($scope.accountID)
.success(function (data, status) {
  $scope.showGetMemberSpinner = false;
  if (!data.HasError) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.account = data.Account;
    $scope.doShowMemberDetails = true;
  } else {
    $scope.getMemberErrorMsg = data.ErrorMsg;
  }
}).
error(function (data, status) {
  $scope.getMemberAjaxErrorMsg = "my message";
  $scope.doShowMemberDetails = false;
  $scope.showGetMemberSpinner = false;

});
```

Service method:

```
memberService.getMember = function (accountID) {
  var params = {};
  params.accountID = accountID;

  var promise = $http({
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    url: '/Admin/Members/GetMember',
  });
  return promise;
};
```

Do I still have too much logic in my controller?

Comment: I am using a  $http interceptors to look into my results if there is an message to show and if there are some requests open to show the spinner take a look here: http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/ - I think it's a bit too much logic in your controller

Comment: I would also say that it's too much logic in the controller. I usually unwrap the promise in the service and then return the actual value/json. Why don't you use something like: <img ng-show="data === undefined" src="loadingSpinnger.gif" />

Comment: @cbass - you return it as a $q deferred?  Any sample you can provide?

Comment: The implementation varies depending on the scope of the problem and how the actual feature is a part of a bigger span. I also usually cache my data(as a promose) in the service which means that I have to check the cache before making the request. But if I were to solve your problem I would probably handle the request in then service and return a $q promise. Then unwrap the promise in the controller only containing either data och error-message.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to handle any ajax errors in the service itself and return a $q promise back to the caller with only the data that comes back instead of the raw ajax response.